# How to extend JSON View in CakePHP 4 to return always the same schema

Tags: json, cakephp

How to extend JSON View in CakePHP 4 to return always the same schema.

For example, in my action `index()` (Endpoint API: GET /api/articles) I have:

```
$this->set(compact('data', 'paging'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['data', 'paging']);
```

But, I would like always have results like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "error": [],
    "data": [
        ..
    ],
    "paging": [
        ..
    ]
```

So, how to make each response have keys like "status" or "error" with default values.

Comment: Assuming that the status isn't always going to be "success", and the errors are going to change depending on what happens in the action. Is there some reason that setting `$status` and `$error` variables and including them in the two `set` calls you have shown won't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is very simple.
Each API controllers extends ApiController class with body:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\EventInterface;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');

        $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('Json');
    }

    /**
     * @inerhitDoc
     */
    public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        $status = true;
        $error = '';

        $this->viewBuilder()->setVars(compact('status', 'error'));
    }

    /**
     * @inerhitDoc
     */
    public function beforeRender(EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeRender($event);

        $this->viewBuilder()->setVar('_serialize', array_keys($this->viewBuilder()->getVars()));
    }
}
```

If I want change `error` or `status` in some controller, I do like this:

```
if ($data->isEmpty()) {
    $this->set([
        'status' => false,
        'error' => __d('api', 'No matching records!'),
    ]);
}
```